# SQL Rolling month sales with last item bought

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to extract a sales report from a database that will include the count of items sold to each customer in the trailing 3 months, plus the description of the latest item bought in that same period.

The database has the following 2 tables:

**Customers table:**

```
+---------+--------------+
|   CID   |   CustName   |
+---------+--------------+
|   001   |     John     |
|   002   |     Marty    |
|   003   |     Roger    |
+---------+--------------+
```

**Sales table:**

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|   CID   |     Make     |    Model    | PurchDate  |
+---------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|   001   |     Ford     |    Focus    | 2018-02-02 |
|   001   |     Dodge    |    Viper    | 2018-01-20 |
|   001   |     Ferrari  |    512      | 2018-01-15 |
|   001   |     BMW      |    M3       | 2017-12-10 |
|   001   |     Tesla    |    S        | 2017-11-05 |
|   002   |     Honda    |    Civic    | 2017-12-18 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

So, assuming we are currently in February 2018 for example, if I run the query I should get the following result:

```
+------------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+---------+
|  CustName  |  -1  |  -2  |  -3  |  LastPurch  |  Make  |  Model  |
+------------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+---------+
|  John      |   2  |   1  |   1  |  2018-01-20 |  Dodge |  Viper  |
|  Marty     |   0  |   1  |   0  |  2017-12-18 |  Honda |  Civic  |
|  Roger     |   0  |   0  |   0  |  null       |  null  |  null   |
+------------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+---------+
```

where column -1 contains the count of items sold to the customer in Jan, -2 the count of items sold in Dec and so on, and the make and model columns contain the details of that customer's latest purchase. Please note that if a customer made no purchase in the reported time frame, its name still appears with 0/null values.

***EDIT:***
I avoided mentioning what I've done so far to keep the question short for the sake of the readers' time.
However, since this led some people to think that I'm trying to unload my work on them, let me explain what I have so far.

I put toghether the following query ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dd9771/3/0)):

```
SELECT Customers.CustName AS 'Customer', Sales.PurchDate AS 'Date of  
Purchase', Sales.Make AS 'Make', Sales.model AS 'Model'
FROM Customers LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales
ON Customers.CID = sales.CID AND Sales.PurchDate >= 
adddate(adddate(last_day(curdate()), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -4 MONTH)
ORDER BY CustName ASC, PurchDate DESC
```

This gives the following result:

```
+------------+------------------+--------+--------+
|  Customer  | Date of Purchase |  Make  |  Model |
+------------+------------------+--------+--------+
|   John     |   2018-02-02     |  Ford  |  Focus |
|   John     |   2018-01-20     |  Dodge |  Viper |
|   John     |   2018-01-15     | Ferrari|  512   |
|   John     |   2017-12-10     |   BMW  |  M3    |
|   John     |   2017-11-05     |  Tesla |  S     |
|   Marty    |   2017-12-18     |  Honda |  Civic |
|   Roger    |   null           |  null  |  null  |
+------------+------------------+--------+--------+
```

This is on the way to to fulfilling the requirement since it shows a 3 rolling month time frame and includes customers that didn't buy anything in the period. So, **my questions are**:

1. How do I create the columns with the sales count per month per customer? I know how to do it as standalone queries that will give the count per single month, but I am cluess as to how to include more than one month in the same result set, let alone integrate with the aforementioned result table. I figure it has to do with sub-queries (maybe?), but that's above my league so a few pointers and directions will be appreciated.
2. How do I obtain only the latest purchase per customer (or null if no purchase at all) from the result table I'm getting so far?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "Gimme teh codez" / "do my work for me"

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this -

```
SELECT C.CustName
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRDATE)-1 = MONTH(PurchDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -1
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRDATE)-2 = MONTH(PurchDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -2
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRDATE)-3 = MONTH(PurchDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -3
      ,MAX(PurchDate)
      ,Make
      ,Model
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Sales S ON C.CID = S.SID
GROUP BY C.CustName, Make, Model
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I appreciate your time Ankit, but your query is not as expected [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dd9771/7)